# auto login to other sites php script

Tags: php, javascript

I want a script by which i can login to other website without opening their login page.

The scenario is like this. I do not want to give login id and password to others.
They just need to click a link or button and script will do its work. It will pass the required login id and password and submit the login form and it is logged in. And client have all the credential.

Comment: You cannot do this without providing a user/pass to the users in some form, even if it's just inside a URL used in a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never trust any site that requires me to enter my username and password for another site. How do I know you are not going to hack my account? Instead use [OpenID](http://openid.net/). This way your users need to log in to the other site and give your site temporary access using a token. All of the major social networking sites support OpenID or similar.