# Auto fill the values in login form of another website

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [auto login to other sites php script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030426/auto-login-to-other-sites-php-script)

I need to open login to many other websites frequently.
So I want to save my time of entering login id and password to login forms.

I want that when i click on the link of any website's login page then it should be open in another tab or popup window. And my script fetch the login id and password from the database and fill in the respective fields in the form. And i need to only click the submit button to get logged in.

Comment: Hm, very generic. You want to write a browser plug-in or so?

Comment: Use Firefox? Chrome? or any other browser that will do this already?

Comment: Please don't double post your questions. If you need to clarify something, you can edit your first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a programmatic approach to this is going to be unnecessarily complicated.

How about a browser plugin instead? http://www.ghacks.net/2007/10/15/use-autologin-in-firefox/

Or [LastPass](http://johnsonyip.com/wordpress/2011/02/17/lastpass-auto-login-add-on-for-internet-explorer-firefox-chrome-browser/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download FireFox: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/
2. Once you have Firefox installed, navigate to the page you'd like to store your login information for.
3. Now, this part is particularly important: After you hit `login`, Firefox will ask you "Would you like Firefox to remember the password for "`yourname`"? Hit `Remember`.
4. Voila! Never worry about typing in your login information again!

Comment: Well, I am aware about tha. But i do not want to type even 1 time. I do not want to do it with client side support rather i am looking for some server side script.

Comment: So what youre saying is, yu'd like to install server-side script on someone else's web server?

Comment: I need to manage it on my website. In the admin area i manage all my accounts on other websites and i need to open all accounts frequently in a day. It may be from any system(computer). 
So I want that I am to just click on a link in the list of all accounts and it should open the respective website login page with login id and password filled automatically.
I need to do it pro-grammatically.

Comment: Ok, but assuming you had to sign up for whatever services you're talking about at one point or another, you'd have to enter your login details at least once, correct?

Comment: yeah correct. First I will sign up or register on that website.

For ex.

I have 2 my own websites . I created their facebook account.
And save their login info in my database on the server.
Now whenever i will work on these facebook acounts. I will just open the list of those accounts and click on the given link to login. login details  will be fetched from database.
Means i have login page url and login detail but want to login without filling the login details manually.

Comment: So why not rely on your browser to store those details for you, rather than wasting time reinventing the wheel?